# How to use elapsed time to code a function to manipulate DOM

Tags: javascript, arrays

new software engineering student here. I have a problem i cant seem to get my head around. I am currently making a basic rhythm game like guitar hero using html,css and javascript.

I managed to run a elapsedTime function that starts a timer running the moment u press start. But i am stuck thinking how to code a function that uses that elapsed time and uses integers/floats from an array and drops notes according to that number in the array. Basically comparing the numbers in the array to the current elapsed time and determining if its the proper time to drop the note. Any suggestions or explanations will be greatly appreciated thank you!!
let elapsedTime = 0;

```js
 
let counter = 0;

function increaseCounter() {
  if (counter >= 10) {
    clearInterval(intervalId); // Stop the interval when the counter reaches 10
    console.log("Interval stopped.");
    return;
  } else {
    counter++;
    console.log(`The counter is ${counter}`);
  }
}

const intervalId = setInterval(increaseCounter, 428.571);
```

Comment: What you have shown looks like it would only update the time _once_, when called - not exactly what I would call "starts a timer running"? You probably want to look into `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for this, which takes a callback and schedules it to be executed before the next repaint. The callback receives a single argument, which is the number of milliseconds since navigation started. You would use it like this:

```js
let start;
let previousTimeStamp;

function step(timeStamp) {
  if (start === undefined) {
    start = timeStamp;
  }
  // elapsed is the number of ms since the 
  // first time step() was called
  const elapsed = timeStamp - start;
  // ... render something,
  // then schedule another frame:
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

Alternatively, [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) gives you the time in ms elapsed since navigation started. The accuracy is limited to ~100 microseconds. You can increase accuracy to ~5 microseconds by serving your page with [the following headers](https://web.dev/articles/coop-coep):

```
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

Alternatively, [`document.timeline.currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationTimeline/currentTime) gives you the elapsed time in milliseconds since the page was loaded. But depending on the browser privacy settings, that value might be off by up to 100 milliseconds.